# What are the linux kernel versions incompatibilities with btrfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, btrfs

I read that usage of a btrfs volume with a newer kernel can render it unreadable when that same volume is used with an older kernel. I have a mobile storage device that will be used by different linux distributions and kernels. What are the kernel version incompatibilities I might have to worry about? The machines I will use have kernel versions 3.2.0, 3.5.0, and higher.

Comment: This is really something to ask on a `btrfs` mailing list. `btrfs` was only announced as no longer unstable very recently, after any of the kernels you mentioned. Potentially using anything before this announcement could cause issues.

Comment: Don't use kernel-version dependent filesystems on moveable storage... VFAT is standard in the area for a reason ;-)